# Camera.Open() giving exception "cannot connect to camera service" on Motorola ET1

Tags: android, android-camera

I have developed a custom camera app , which is running correctly on all Samsung and Nexus devices.

But on `Motorola ET1 (Android 4.1.1)` it works sometime , and sometimes randomly it gives run-time exception `cannot connect to camera service` on :

```
camera = Camera.open();
```

I have also added these lines `onDestroy()` and `surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)` methods:

```
if(camera != null)
{
    camera.unlock();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
```

After this exception whenever I open `default camera app of Motorola` , and close it. My custom camera app also starts to work fine.

Is there any problem with the default camera app or my custom camera app ?

Comment: I am facing same problem whenever I do hardware scan and then open the camera.